# Replace image source and attribute adding stops after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
<div id="fbAdsIconDiv" class="social_icon">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/fbAdsAddOn_1.png" onclick="toggleImage(this)" id="fbAdsAddOn" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                        title="click to enable" class="confirmBox fb_ads-icon" /></div>
```

what i doing is that i have two images i.e. **fbAdsAddOn_1.png**  and **fbAdsAddOn_2.png**.For this i am simply using below Jquery code to replace image with some extra attributes:

```
$(".social_icon img").each(function () {
            var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', imgsrc.replace('2', '1'));
            $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'click to enable');
            $(this).attr('data-target', '');
            $(this).attr('data-toggle', '');
        });

function loadNewLocation(leadId) {
        var form = $('#brand-add-form');
        var summary = form.find('[data-valmsg-summary="true"]'); // get summary
        summary.hide(); // hide to avoid flicker

        $.ajax({
            url: '/locations/_createwizarditem',
            data: { index: location_count , leadId: leadId},
            success: function (data) {
                alert((data));
                $('.location-setup').last().after($.parseHTML($.trim(data)));
                //$('.location-setup').last().after($(data));
                location_count += 1;
                addAsterisk(); 
                initStateDropdown();
                reinitializeValidator($('#brand-add-form'));
                prevStep();
                prevStep();


                summary.show();
            },
            error: function (response) {
                toastr.error("Something went wrong loading a new location", 'Oh No!');
                console.error(response);
                summary.show();
            }
        })
    }
```

It works first time but it stops working after AJAX call...how can i resolve this?????

Comment: Where's your ajax call?

Comment: @CarlEdwards with ajax call i am just calling the view only..

Comment: It doesn't *"stop"* after ajax call. You likely never call it when ajax call succeeds. Please show all relevant code

Comment: and the view that you are loading in the ajax call contains the `.social_icon` section? if that is the case i think @charlietfl might be right about the issue. and apart from the issue you are facing try assigning all the attributes in a single call `.attr({attribute:value,})` or use `.prop()` instead.

Comment: @charlietfl updated ajax code.please elaborate what i am doing wrong..thanks

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam please see updated code

Comment: Need to look for those same images in the new html and do the same thing as you do on page load

Comment: @charlietfl this is one part i have several functions which does different things on different images so like some work on change or something so what to do in that case..it becomes tedious job then

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to replace the image after success Ajax call. Just put the replace function in success event;

```
            success: function (data) {
                alert((data));
                $('.location-setup').last().after($.parseHTML($.trim(data)));
                //$('.location-setup').last().after($(data));
                location_count += 1;
                addAsterisk(); 
                initStateDropdown();
                reinitializeValidator($('#brand-add-form'));
                prevStep();
                prevStep();
                $(".social_icon img").each(function () {
                    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
                    $(this).attr('src', imgsrc.replace('1', '2'));
                    $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'click to enable');
                    $(this).attr('data-target', '');
                    $(this).attr('data-toggle', '');
                });
                summary.show();
            }
```

Comment: Is your ajax call completing with success ? Are you sure about that ?

Comment: @Raniman simple question what if i have used 5 more functions on same html then do i need to call here again after success and one thing more all functions performs differently like some work on dropdown change

Comment: I updated the answer. "$(this).attr('src', imgsrc.replace('1', '2'));"

Comment: "imgsrc.replace('1', '2')" is it constant ? How is determined replace values 1 to 2 ?